# Vectors calculating angeles

Tags: vectors

For the question http://vvcap.net/db/GQzsc65pNEHVfSKQfV1g.htp

I have the following : http://vvcap.net/db/zkekuH9dXTKOJYGkt4dp.htp

I'm pretty sure it's correct and I can follow the template however I don't know actually how to sum it all up to get an angle =/ stupid I know, but could someone explain to me how I can find the angle in degrees, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get the following :

$$\begin{align}\frac{-8\times(-23)+15\times 7}{\sqrt{(-8)^2+(15)^2}\times\sqrt{(-23)^2+7^2}}&=\frac{289}{\sqrt{289}\times\sqrt{2\times 289}}\\&=\frac{289}{\sqrt{289}\times\sqrt 2\times \sqrt{289}}\\&=\frac{289}{289\times \sqrt 2}\\&=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\\&=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}.\end{align}$$

Here, note that $\sqrt{289}\times\sqrt{289}=289.$

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get an angle from the squareroot of 2/2

Comment: From the table that was given in the original question.

Comment: hey are you online, could you explain to me where the 289 x 2 x 289 comes from.. please?

Comment: @user119325: $(-8)^2+(15)^2=289, (-23)^2+7^2=2\times 289.$

Comment: how did you get 1/squareroot 2? when I do the step before that I just got a huge decimal number rather than 1/squareroot2

Comment: @user119325: I added a bit. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But, all these outputs are just huge decimal numbers ( if you haven't noticed already, i'm pretty clueless with maths.)

Comment: @user119325 : In this case, you don't need to use such huge decimal numbers. Usually we can find a way without using huge decimal numbers.

Comment: how the hell do I convert e.g. 3.00404044004 to 1/squareroot2 this makes no sense to me

Comment: do you mean you convert $1/\sqrt 2$ to $0.707106781186548...$?